# Nginx keeps redirecting on a base install of laravel forge

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx, forge

Although I do not have laravel setup on the server I am just trying to display some php files

In my root directory I have /public/dashboard which is executed by domain.com/dashboard

It shows up fine but as soon as I try to append something to "dashboard" it redirects back to /dashboard

For example type domain.com/dashboard/test it goes back to domain.com/dashboard

I have nothing in my htaccess file. Here is my nginx config:

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/domain.com/before/*;

server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
server_name jackco.biz;
root /home/forge/domain.com/public;

# FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.com/292197/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.com/292197/server.key;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers '';
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

#add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

index index.html index.htm index.php;

charset utf-8;

# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/domain.com/server/*;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

access_log off;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/domain.com-error.log error;

error_page 404 /index.php;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
}

location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
    deny all;
}
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/domain.com/after/*;
```

Any thoughts to disable the constant redirect/rewite?